# Creating an array out of another array between 2 elements

Tags: python, arrays, file, readfile, texas-instruments

I am reading a file in python using readlines()

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

How can I add all the components in lines that appear between 2 specific characters for example:

```
lines = [rose, 1 , 2 , 4 , 5, 6], garden, plants ]
```

I want to create an array out of lines such that:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Try at your own. If you have a specific question then, show your code and ask.

Comment: At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, ot other... And then we will help you!

Comment: Is the whole "data: " + array in one line?

Comment: yes it is all in the same line

Comment: changed the question @JonathanGagne

Comment: @MichaelButscher have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should help:

```
# Open File
with open('../input_file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Find the required attribute
for line in lines:
    if line[:4] == 'data':
        data = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        break

# Split the content to make a list of INTEGERS
python_list = map(lambda x : int(x.strip()),data[1:-1].split(','))
```

It provides a list of Integers as the data is numerical.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Read File
file = open("testFile.txt", "r")
f_str=file.read()
# Find positions of  [] in String
begin_pos= f_str.find('[')+1
end_pos= f_str.find(']')
# Get Subset of String and Split it by ',' in a Str List
f_str=f_str[begin_pos:end_pos].split(',')
#Str List to Int List
plist=list(map(int, f_str))
#Test it
print(plist)
print(type(plist[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    data = content[8][7:].split(",")
```